# Old question in Review Triage queue, displayed as new question

Tags: bug, review

I just started reviewing as a 'newbie' and found something strange. Maybe it's normal behaviour, that is, if an old question can pop up in the triage review queue again.

Review page:
[image]

(asked: today, viewed: 2 times)

Then I clicked on the link and opened the question, because I saw old comments (from May this year) on the "Just now" asked question:
[Fast bit shift of a byte array - CMAC subkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350492/fast-bit-shift-of-a-byte-array-cmac-subkeys)

[image]

(asked: 28 days ago, viewed: 106 times)

How can this be? Bug?

Answer (score 6):

Not a bug: It's just a review audit, to test if you're paying attention.

The system lies and says that it was new to fool you.

I guess it should be posted as a new bug that timestamps on comments on audits aren't changed.

Comment: Ahh. I see. I did pay attention, maybe too much :)

http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug